# Uploading program to a MCU

Tags: microcontroller, digital-communications

I'd like to start my own personal project on making a small device using MCU.
I am currently researching the things that I need to know and buy.

I think I am going to use MCU bluenrg by STM.
I was looking at the data sheet. It seems like we need upload instructions to the flash memory within chips in order to have desired actions.

In order to do so, don't I need a USB to I2C module or USB to SPI module, do I?

Thank you.
https://www.st.com/en/wireless-connectivity/bluenrg-2.html

Comment: First buy their evaluation board, which is likely to have a simple USB programming interface. Once you are familiar with it, you can look into your own board design.

Comment: Do you have any experience before ?

Comment: @LongPham not really...  I just programmed on seeed arch pro. I am being ambitious here. But again, I am researching to see if I will be capable of doing this and such

Comment: @user167987 Frankly, no. You won't be able to make an MCU board from scratch with no experience.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Okay. I get it. I was starting to think that. What do you recommend that I start with? Evaluation board as you recommended?

Comment: Yes. Even professionals start with that to get familiar with new technology. Then you can open it's schematic to see how it is done, or look at some reference designs.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I wanted to start simply from manipulating GPIO, turning on LEDs and then expand from on. 
(I have used LCD / accelerometer modules, programmed UART with FPGA and such....)

Comment: ST makes many different Nucleo boards where: "programming" the board is simply copying the binary to a virtual thumb drive that the board creates when plugged in.  It doesnt get any simpler than this, others you will need an IDE or tool to do the programming, usually you have what you need on the board.  Then breakouts you will need additional hardware.  some the interface they provide to do programming also has a virtual uart, others you have to buy extra hardware to get the uart.  Not all the nucleos have the uart thing.  shop around.

Comment: good thing these days is from most of these vendors the eval/play boards are in the $10 to $20 range.  With some  you can re-use the debug half of the board for your own board designs or designs that are more of a breakout, like some of the BLE boards that you can buy in that price range.

Comment: the specific details of how to program X chip first are read the documentation for that chip, then the board you are using then the ide/tools you are using if you are using sandboxed tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to the business - **buy a development kit first**, eg. [STEVAL-IDB008V2](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/solution-evaluation-tools/communication-and-connectivity-solution-eval-boards/steval-idb008v2.html) (or boards from Silicon Labs or Nordic Semi - they make similar Bluetooth chips). You will learn a lot even if you don't design the PCB.

Comment: Actually that's what I want to do. Design a PCB.

Comment: I want to get to the lowest level possible. I have looked into STEVAL-IDB008V2 also.

Comment: Though, I am not sure... It seems quite expensive. Even if I fail, I think I will start with the MCU chip, using QFN adapter.

Answer (score 0):

"I'd like to start my own personal project on making a small device using MCU....I think I am going to use MCU bluenrg by STM"

You may wish to start with

"Information on how to use the STM32 Nucleo board with mbed. Getting Started with BlueNRG Shield" 
https://os.mbed.com/teams/ST-Americas-mbed-Team/wiki/Get-Started-with-BlueNRG

"BlueNRG shield for STM32 Nucleo"
https://www.carminenoviello.com/2015/03/08/bluenrg-shield-stm32-nucleo/

Comment: I would recommend to stay away from mbed and similar stuff, hiding the real way the things are working. Unless one doesn't want to learn but have some quick and dirty way of doing certain things.

Comment: Those guys, STMicroelectronics do know a thing or two on the subject, and they do place the logo ARMmbed on Nucleo devices thus recommending mbed.  It really is an excellent way to get into microcontrollers.

Comment: @SergeySukhotinsky I have already used mbed just for learning purpose and I have to agree with Eugen Sh. I don't want to use mbed...
I am starting this project to, for example, program I2C protocole myself and etc. I think this makes a big difference if I want to work in this field.